# How to query a different database using Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to query another database from EF Core just to get another data, I don't want to create a DB Context because I don't want to modify this database. How can i do this? I have been using Dapper for this but i'm upgrading to Asp .NET Core 3.1 and cutting on dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can always change your context connection string

```
your_context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
```

But generally, the correct way would be to create a new context with 2 connection strings. You mentioned that you don't want to modify the database but a context is simply a class and it doesn't modify anything unless you tell it to. So my suggestion is to create 2 contexts because is more maintainable and modular.

Comment: Thanks but the best approach I came up with is just make a view and call that view